# why Function.prototype.call() executed before console.log()?

Tags: javascript

why Function.prototype.call() executed before console.log()?

```js
function Product(name, price) {
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;
}

function Food() {
  console.log(this)
  Product.call(this, 'cheese', 5);
  this.category = 'food';
}
new Food()
```

[image]

Comment: It's not, it's just the console is a live view.

Comment: And `this.category = 'food';` is ran before you open it

Comment: Hover over the blue **i** symbol and it'd inform you of this behaviour. If you print an object to the console and expand it later, you'd see its *current state*, not the state it was at the time of logging. The logged reference is live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not executing before the `console.log`, as others mentioned, it is caused by the live reference to that object, so you will always see the newest value of the object.

**Check the example**

```js
function Product(name, price) {
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;
}

function Food() {
  console.log(this)
  Product.call(this, 'cheese', 5);
  console.log(this)
  this.category = 'food';
}
new Food()
```

**Update**

You can see the current value if you are not opening the object (the first is an empty object `{}`, the second got values), I pointed it with arrows. If you open the object you will see the live reference, which is the same for both logs.

[image]